# How to repeat ajax request after condition

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello guys I want to do one thing: from back end i receive a number and if it's equal to one i want to do one condition and if it's equal to 2 i want to repeat ajax, until condition would be equal to one, can someone explain me how to do it? :) here is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".match").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/matchmaking.php',
            success: function (data) {
              alert("Isejo" + data);
              //if data is equal to 1 do this 
              //if data is equal to 2 repeat ajax request
            }
            });
          });
        });
        </script>
```

p.s. i am getting data from back end using php
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Why doesn't the back end do whatever is needed in one request? You don't appear to be sending any data so seems like a strange approach

Comment: You might want to use websockets. Something like https://github.com/voryx/Thruway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function getData(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      if(data.id === 1){
        console.log('is equal to 1 do this')
      }  
      if(data.id === 2){
        console.log('call getData again')
      getData()
      }
    }
  })
}

getData()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Wrap ajax in function and call it from inside it on appropriate condition.

It can make infinite loop, but I'm sure you are aware of that

Comment: Hey i am aware of that, maybe it's possible to break this kind of the loop with for example some kind of function? :)

Comment: another if with some state to check, `var state = 'cancel' .............. if(state === cancel)...` or something like that

Comment: another think some delay between ajax request's will by polite for server

Comment: @JonasTamoševičius the above answer is correct but to be sure that the method is called when the ajax call is completed you can write the same logic in `.done()` method of ajax instead of `success` this lets the ajax call to finish and make another call. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do jQuery trigger to repeat ajax request.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oncourse = false;
  $(".match").click(function() { // can be changed to id selection - $('#match')
    if (oncourse == true) return;
    oncourse = true;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'includes/matchmaking.php',
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == '1') {
          // do something
          oncourse = false;
        } else if (data == "2") {
         // do something
          oncourse = false;
          $('.match').trigger('click');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes you can do that but, in all probability, you don't want any chance of two recursive processes running simultaneously. Therefore, it would be wise to detach the click handler during the recursive process and reattach on completion.

Comment: It will not reattach twice as the attachment was only called once, `trigger('click')` only triggers the event and does not create another click handler.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I suggest detaching the click handler to prevent further clicks by the user starting second, third, fourth etc, parallel recursive processes. If that detachment was made, then `trigger('click')` would have no effect.

Comment: Actually, there's another point. We don't know how many `.match` elements there are. `$('.match').trigger('click')` would trigger all of them not just the one in question.

Comment: ^ That's for the first issue. Can't address the second point as I don't know the full context. Maybe the handler is for all `.click` elements.

Comment: Yes, looks like it should work. Retriggering 'click' on only the original element is quite simple. The element is given by `event.target`, where `event` is exposed as the click handler's first parameter.